# Css Preloader in apex take a while to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, preloader

I am using a css preloader for apex web application. problem is that  it takes a while to load after any click , so 1st 1 or 2 seconds it doesn't appear.  i want it to b started at the moment when i click something.  how to make it load immediately?
Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('slow',function(){$(this).remove();});
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing slow to **fast** like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  


    $(window).load(function(){.
        $('#preloader').fadeOut('fast',function(){$(this).remove();});
    });

    }); 
    </script>
```

or you can also use time duration, check this [link](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) for further reference..